# ASP.NET MVC 2: Avoiding loop when accessing 404 action directly

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, http-status-code-404

Like many people using ASP.NET MVC, I've implemented my own custom 404 error handling scheme using an approach similar to the one described here: [How can I properly handle 404 in ASP.NET MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/619895/how-can-i-properly-handle-404s-in-asp-net-mvc/2577095#2577095)

(I actually discovered that post after implementing my own solution, but what I came up with is virtually identical.)

However, I ran into one issue I'm not sure how to properly handle. Here's what my 404 action in my ErrorController class looks like:

```
    public ActionResult NotFound(string url)
    {
        url = (url ?? "");

        if (Request.Url.OriginalString.Contains(url) &&
            Request.Url.OriginalString != url)
        {
            url = Request.Url.OriginalString;
        }

        url = new Uri(url).AbsolutePath;

        // Check URL to prevent 'retry loop'
        if (url != "/Error/NotFound")
        {
            Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.NotFound;

            // Log 404 error just in case something important really is
            // missing from the web site...
            Elmah.ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(
                new HttpException(Response.StatusCode,
                    String.Format("Resource not found: {0}", url)));
        }

        return View();
    }
```

The part that's different from the answer in the other StackOverflow question I referenced above is how the 'retry loop' is prevented. In other other answer, the code that prevents the retry loop simply sets properties on a ViewModel, which doesn't seem to actually prevent the loop. Since the action is sending back a response code of 404, then accessing the action directly (by typing "/Error/NotFound" in the browser) causes an infinite loop.

So here's my question: Did I miss another, more obvious way to handle the retry loop issue, or is my approach a decent way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

you can handel erros by enabling the `customErrors` mode in the web.config file and set it to redirect errors to your controller when any errors occurs.

see an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3605703/mvc-2-0-routes-redirect-request-ignore-request/3607258#3607258)

Comment: Actually, using web.config in ASP.NET MVC to handle 404 errors isn't recommended because ASP.NET returns a 302/Redirect status code in that case (to redirect the user to your error page) rather than a 404.